# How to customize AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to customize an `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler`, but I have no idea how to do this.  How can I override the default `SimpleUncaughtExceptionHandler` configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in details [in the Javadoc of `@EnableAsync`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) as specified in the [developer guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-enable-annotation-support)

You need to implement `AsyncConfigurer` to customize how async processing works.